# conversion between Window, GdkWindow and GtkWindow

Tags: linux, gtk, x11

Confused between Window, GdkWindow and GtkWindow.

Is there any api for conversion from Window to GdkWindow and then to GtkWindow.

Comment: I wrote about the difference between GdkWindow and GtkWindow [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27515062/difference-between-gtkwindow-and-gdkwindow/27515738#27515738). `Window` is the data type of the window manager window provided by X11 when you use Xlib (other X11 libraries use different names, for instance `xcb_window_t` in xcb).

Comment: I'll update that answer to mention all of that soon. As for converting, I'm not sure if it's possible...

Comment: ok thanks andlabs. waiting for your answer

Comment: @andlabs so xcb_window_t is the same thing as the x11 window?

Comment: @Noitidart Yes, or rather it is the type that stores the window's ID (if I recall correctly, anyway).

Comment: Sweet thanks my thing wasn't working I was suspecting this was it, but it can't be then. I'll look in other direciton. Thanks!